# Group by two criteria and append names together to form one cell on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have

[image]

I want to create a new dataframe by doing a Group By on Account and Date and putting the names together in one cell.

Thus at the end of the day we should have

```
Account    Name             Date

1          Bob, Rob, Joe     1/1/2020
```

I am not sure how to do this in Python

Comment: try : df.groupby(['Account','Date'])['Name'].agg(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=', '))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iiuc you search for `df.groupby(...).agg(list)` - but you don't make it clear if you aim for a string concatenation or a list of names...

```
df.groupby(['Account', 'Date'], as_index=False).Name.agg(list)

#    Account      Date             Name
# 0        1  1.1.2020  [Bob, Rob, Joe]
```